# shared_mutex prototype implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, linux, lock-free

Anyone feels to review a *prototype* C++11 shared_mutex implementation?

Not recursive, not protected and potentially dangerous if used incorrectly, but allegedly *fast* in case of *many R/O less R/W* operations on multi-core CPUs.

Again, this is not code supposed to run in production as it is, but still, if used correctly it's supposed to work fine.

Link: https://github.com/Emanem/shared_mutex

Code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <array>
#include <thread>

// this should be defined in the Makefile
// if not defined, use what is most common
// for x86_64 CPUs in 2017...
#ifndef LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE
#define LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE  64
#endif

namespace ema {
    template<size_t N>
    class shared_mutex {
        // purpose of this structure is to hold
        // status of each individual bucket-mutex
        // object
        // Ideally each thread should be mapped to
        // one entry only of 'el_' during its
        // lifetime
        struct entry_lock {
            const static uint64_t   W_MASK = 0x8000000000000000,
                        R_MASK = ~W_MASK;

            // purpose ot this variable is to hold
            // in the first bit (W_MASK) if we're locking
            // in exclusive mode, otherwise use the
            // reamining 63 bits to count how many R/O
            // locks we share in this very bucket
            std::atomic<uint64_t>   wr_lock;

            entry_lock() : wr_lock(0) {
            }
        } __attribute__((aligned(LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE)));
        // array holding all the buckets
        std::array<entry_lock, N>   el_;
        // atomic variable used to initialize thread
        // ids so that they should evenly spread
        // across all the buckets
        static std::atomic<size_t>  idx_hint_;
        // lock-free function to return a 'unique' id
        static uint64_t get_hint_idx(void) {
            while(true) {
                size_t cur_hint = idx_hint_.load();
                if(idx_hint_.compare_exchange_weak(cur_hint, cur_hint+1))
                    return cur_hint;
            }
        }
        // get index for given thread
        // could hav used something like std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id())
        // but honestly using a controlled idx_hint_
        // seems to be better in terms of putting threads
        // into buckets evenly
        // note - thread_local is supposed to be static...
        inline static size_t get_thread_idx(void) {
            const thread_local size_t   rv = get_hint_idx()%N;
            return rv;
        }
    public:
        shared_mutex() {
        }

        void lock_shared(void) {
            // try to replace the wr_lock with current value incremented by one
            while(true) {
                size_t  cur_rw_lock = el_[get_thread_idx()].wr_lock.load();
                if(entry_lock::W_MASK & cur_rw_lock) {
                    // if someone has got W access yield and retry...
                    std::this_thread::yield();
                    continue;
                }
                if(el_[get_thread_idx()].wr_lock.compare_exchange_weak(cur_rw_lock, cur_rw_lock+1))
                    break;
            }
        }

        void unlock_shared(void) {
            // try to decrement the count
            while(true) {
                size_t  cur_rw_lock = el_[get_thread_idx()].wr_lock.load();
#ifndef _RELEASE
                if(entry_lock::W_MASK & cur_rw_lock)
                    throw std::runtime_error("Fatal: unlock_shared but apparently this entry is W_MASK locked!");
#endif //_RELEASE
                if(el_[get_thread_idx()].wr_lock.compare_exchange_weak(cur_rw_lock, cur_rw_lock-1))
                    break;
            }
        }

        void lock(void) {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                // acquire all locks from all buckets
                while(true) {
                    size_t  cur_rw_lock = el_[i].wr_lock.load();
                    if(cur_rw_lock != 0) {
                        std::this_thread::yield();
                        continue;
                    }
                    // if cur_rw_lock is 0 then proceed
                    if(el_[i].wr_lock.compare_exchange_weak(cur_rw_lock, entry_lock::W_MASK))
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        void unlock(void) {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                // release all locks
                while(true) {
                    size_t  cur_rw_lock = el_[i].wr_lock.load();
#ifndef _RELEASE
                    if(cur_rw_lock != entry_lock::W_MASK)
                        throw std::runtime_error("Fatal: unlock but apparently this entry is shared locked or uninitialized!");
#endif //_RELEASE
                    // then proceed resetting to 0
                    if(el_[i].wr_lock.compare_exchange_weak(cur_rw_lock, 0))
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        ~shared_mutex() {
        }
    };

    template<size_t N>
    std::atomic<size_t> shared_mutex<N>::idx_hint_{0};

    // utility class for exclusive RAII lock
    template<size_t N>
    class x_lock {
        shared_mutex<N>&    sm_;
    public:
        x_lock(shared_mutex<N>& sm) : sm_(sm) {
            sm_.lock();
        }

        ~x_lock() {
            sm_.unlock();
        }
    };

    // utility class for share RAII lock
    template<size_t N>
    class s_lock {
        shared_mutex<N>&    sm_;
    public:
        s_lock(shared_mutex<N>& sm) : sm_(sm) {
            sm_.lock_shared();
        }

        ~s_lock() {
            sm_.unlock_shared();
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks!